# Application of CLT for bounded random variables with slowly decreasing variance

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $(X_k)_{k\in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of independent random variables and $M> 0$ such that $$\forall n\in \mathbb N: |X_n| \leq M$$
>   and $\sum_{k\in \mathbb N}\mathrm{Var}(X_k) = \infty$. Define $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$. Prove that $$\frac{S_n-\mathbb E[S_n]}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(S_n)}} \longrightarrow \mathcal N(0,1)$$
>   in distribution.

Attempt:
I don't think I can solve this using the "standard" CLT for i.i.d. random variables, since I don't know if it's possible to make the $X_n$ to be identically distributed.
So I try to use the Lindeberg-CLT. To that end, define $\left(\left(X_{n,k}\right)_{k=1}^n \right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ by
$$X_{n,k} := \frac{S_k - \mathbb E[S_k]}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(S_n)}}.$$
One easily sees that this defines an independent, standardized triangular array. So if the Lindeberg condition holds we may conclude that $$\sum_{l=1}^n X_{n,l} \longrightarrow \mathcal N(0,1).$$
Now I don't know if that is helpful or not, and I was unable to prove the Lindeberg condition so far. Is this even going in the right direction?

Comment: Without the boundedness assumption $|X_n|\leq M$ this would not necessarily be true (i.e., we would not necessarily converge to a Gaussian distribution).  But that boundedness assumption helps prove the Lindeberg condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: in order to check Lindeberg's condition, we have to treat terms of the form $\mathbb E\left[Y_j^2\mathbf 1\left\{  Y_j^2\gt \varepsilon \operatorname{Var\left(S_n\right)}\right\}\right]$, where $Y_j:=X_j-\mathbb E\left[X_j\right]$. Note that $\left\lvert Y_j\right\rvert$ is bounded by $2M$  hence what can you say about $\mathbf 1\left\{  Y_j^2\gt \varepsilon \operatorname{Var\left(S_n\right)}\right\}$ when $n$ is sufficiently large?

Comment: Thanks! I actually had this term appear but was afraid that this estimate was too rough. Can we conclude right after Lindeberg is proved, i.e. does $\sum_{l=1}^n X_{n,l} \longrightarrow \mathcal N(0,1)$ imply the statement?

Comment: Nvm, I see it now. I defined my $X_{n,k}$ slightly wrong. :)